# Exception thrown: 'Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm a rookie in most languages of coding and I'm trying to follow the [Autodesk Forge tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/rundebug/2legged_da). I'm trying to achieve the 'modify your model' tutorial. On the Run & Debug step I try to upload my model but nothing much happens after that. The output from debugging says `Exception thrown: 'Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`  and then exits all kinds of threads.

I'm using:

- C#
- .NET Core 3.1
- Visual Studio 2022 (but I also tried 2019)
- the 3.* versions of the added NuGet packages because the tutorial told me so, I'm kind of afraid my system wants me to use newer versions but that results in other errors.

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide full stack trace, I just now tested on VS 2022, .NET Core 3.1, everything seems to be working.
The list of packages - Autodesk.Forge 1.9.1, Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation 3.02

Comment: The properties from my project:

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autodesk.Forge" Version="1.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.29" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Can you share the full stack of exception, you should see that in debug window and debug command line ? If it didn't solve, please book a slot, I can assist you https://calendly.com/autodeskforge/madhukar-moogala?month=2022-09